# NullPointerException / CursorOutOfBoundsException when attempting to get data from SQLite db

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

[edit] logcat added

Per the title. It was something that I had anticipated would happen when I would try to recover data from the database and there would be nothing in so I tried to avoid it.

Currently I have a User class that takes three arguments (String, String, int). I also have the following method in a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public User retrieveUserInfo() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USER, null);


        String name = null;
        String surname = null;
        String age = null;

        if (cursor == null) {
            Log.d("NULL", "CURSOR IS NULL");
            user = new User("Please connect to server", " ", 0);

        }

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 

            Log.d("NOT NULL", "CURSOR IS NOT NULL");

            do {
                name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME));
                surname = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SURNAME));
                age = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_AGE));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            Log.d("NAME", name);
            int age_p = Integer.parseInt(age);
            user = new User(name, surname, age_p);

        }



        return user;
    }
```

I then call this method from another activity thusly:

```
DatabaseTask dt = new DatabaseTask(this);
        User user = dt.retrieveUserInfo();
        String name = user.getName();
        String surname = user.getSurname();

        TextView textName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView textSurname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        textName.setText(name);
        textSurname.setText(surname);
```

So, currently I'm trying to avoid having crashes by sending a User instance with some placeholder fields back when the cursor is null (the "user" field in this method is a public static member variable of type User, defined earlier in the class) and returning the normal data stored in the database when the cursor is not null. It still doesn't work, though: as soon as I uninstall the app and reinstall it, the app crashes. Now, if I insert something in the database and then re-install the app without first removing it (updating it and keeping the old database, I guess) the app does not crash.

Any ideas on why my check for the cursor being null or not does not work?

[edit] logcat follows:

```
> 03-17 02:48:35.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1225): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 03-17 02:48:35.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1225): Process:
> com.example.jsonbourne, PID: 1225 03-17 02:48:35.036:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1225): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
> activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.jsonbourne/com.example.jsonbourne.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException 03-17 02:48:35.036:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1225):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
> 03-17 02:48:35.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
> 03-17 02:48:35.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 03-17
> 02:48:35.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
> 03-17 02:48:35.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 03-17
> 02:48:35.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 03-17 02:48:35.036:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1225):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 03-17
> 02:48:35.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-17
> 02:48:35.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 03-17 02:48:35.036:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1225):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
> 03-17 02:48:35.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 03-17
> 02:48:35.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-17 02:48:35.036:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1225): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> 03-17 02:48:35.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):   at
> com.example.jsonbourne.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
> 03-17 02:48:35.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):   at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 03-17
> 02:48:35.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):     at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
> 03-17 02:48:35.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
> 03-17 02:48:35.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):   ... 11 more
```

[edit 2] MainActivity and activity_mail.xml follow:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //GetJson gj = new GetJson(this);
        //gj.getData();

        DatabaseTask dt = new DatabaseTask(this);

        User user = dt.retrieveUserInfo(); // **<------- LINE 31**



        String name = user.getName();
        String surname = user.getSurname();

        TextView textName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView textSurname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        textName.setText(name);
        textSurname.setText(surname); 

        Button buttonconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_connect);
```

activity_mail.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_connect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="188dp"
        android:background="#F0FF00"
        android:text="@string/pressconnect" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_connect"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_connect"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Welcome,"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What did the logcat say about your app crash?

Comment: Donfuxx made a nice observation, you could avoid errors like this with a static analysis tools, like FindBugs and Google CodePro.

Comment: The cursor won't be null after `rawQuery()`. An exception can be thrown or an empty cursor can be returned, but null won't be returned. The problem is elsewhere - please post your exception stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: I will post the logcat very soon (as soon as the emulator decides to start, honestly!)

Comment: Problem in `MainActivity.java:31` - please post your `MainActivity` `onCreate()` and indicate row 31. Include any XML layouts too in case layout widgets are referenced nearby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in question

```
DatabaseTask dt = new DatabaseTask(this);

User user = dt.retrieveUserInfo(); // **<------- LINE 31**

String name = user.getName();
```

cannot really produce the stacktrace, so let's assume the NPE really occurs on the next line by calling `getName()` on `null` `user`. That can be fixed by fixing `retrieveUserInfo()` for example like this:

```
Cursor cursor = ...;

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
  // create user from cursor data
} else {
  // create default user
}
return user;
```

The `cursor` `null` check is not necessary as mentioned in comments.

Also, your query fetches all rows from the table but only uses data from the last one. Later you may want to consider optimizing that i.e. only fetch the data that you actually use.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked! Just wondering though, how can the "user" object be null if the "cursor" itself is not?

Comment: Because you never initialize it - no code branch where it is initialized got executed.

Comment: Oh, about the second part of your advice, which I totally forgot to address:  I know that I'm getting all the users to use only one (the last one) - it was just a bit of test code. In fact, in the finished app, I expect to have only one row with a lot of colums to save the details of only one user (the one that logged in) so I'll have to fetch only one row anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
    if (cursor == null) {
        Log.d("NULL", "CURSOR IS NULL");
        user = new User("Please connect to server", " ", 0);

    } else if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
        Log.d("NOT NULL", "CURSOR IS NOT NULL");
        //...
    }
```

Instead of:

```
    if (cursor == null) {
        Log.d("NULL", "CURSOR IS NULL");
        user = new User("Please connect to server", " ", 0);

    }

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
```

Looks like you had forgotten the `else` statement

Comment: Thanls for your answer! I left out the "else" statement in this particular code instance but I had tried it earlier and it still wouldn't work, unfortunately.